# Corsair Temperature Report

Tags: power-supply

I have a Corsair AX 1200i that reports its temperature and its fan rotation speed to the desktop. I like to know

- Which point of PSU is measured.
- What is the normal working temperature of a PSU.
- If temperature= 50 degrees C is alarming when fan speed shows 0 rotation.

If I am at the wrong place for this question, pleas instruct me to right place.

Edit 1 : Please read carefully this question is about a PSU. As you read I said I have "some" power supply that reports its temperature and fan speed. Why do you know this off topic of an electronic question site?

Comment: You must contact the manufacturer of the PSU to ask about this. It is just one more electronic device among millions, and you can't expect people who never even saw it to be familiar with its design or construction.

Comment: This question would be a better fit at superuser.SE, electronics.SE is focused on questions regarding designing and repairing circuits.

Comment: "If I am..., pleas instruct me to right place" reads as: "Hey, I have no time to spend myself on finding out what the hell I am asking and where I should do that, you guys take some of your very valuable time to figure it out for me and then get things sorted. kthxbai" We're volunteers, not your personal aid workers. If I could I'd vote -3 just for that.

Comment: @Asmy: +1 for you and -1 for the OP.  And on top of that, we're just supposed to know what a "Corsair AX 1200i" is!?  *Screw this!*

Comment: @Asmyldof ."Open for new assignments, always willing to help a tiny bit for free." All your comment means "Hey, I am an arrogant expert that know nothing about your question and hide my ignorant by attacking." In contrast I have spent plenty of time searching for this. Even Corsair site had nothing about that except repeating marketing materials. Why do you use abusive word "hell" instead of kindly referring me to a right place such as superuser.SE similar to jms. People have different capacity in using internet and might hit the wrong place without bad intention. Be humble mate.

Comment: @Asmyldof, When was it that I asked you to become my personal aid worker. You invited yourself for personal fulfilment to answer the question. Perhaps if you could you would exile me to Siberia for asking a question that you do not like.

Comment: @OlinLathrop. "You are not <i>supposed</i> to know". You are invited to answer voluntarily "if you know what is that about." <i>Screw that!</i>.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Sir, please read the question carefully. One who is familiar with the design of a PSU can answer that regardless of manufacturer, as one gentleman here has answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the temperature is measured using a thermistor mounted on the heatsink. If there are more heatsinks then there can be more thermistors or the thermistor is mounted on the hetasink that is expected to be the hottest.

A normal working temperature for a heatsink can be 80 degrees C or more.

50 degrees C is considered "cool" for electronics. I would only worry when the temperature is always above 70 to 80 degrees C.

But don't worry too much about all this, Corsair makes decent supplies, the fan will switch on when needed.

Comment: Thank you Sir, You have duly answered the question as you read it carefully. Your profile in contrast to attacking people shows that you are not carrying tons of professional arrogance.